# PHP, file_get_contents() returning null for PDF files

Tags: php, pdf

I would like to get content of a pdf file into a variable. I tried to do this using

> file_get_contents("file.pdf")

but it's returning NULL.  If I do the same with .jpg file for example it's working. Any idea how to overcome this problem? Is there another way? Thanks in advance!

**Edit:**

**Service code:**

```
<?php

function sendAttachment($msg){
$responsePayloadString = <<<XML
    <payload:receiveReport xmlns:payload="http://wso2.org/wsfphp/samples/mtom">
        <payload:reports> 
            <payload:report>
                <payload:content xmlmime:contentType="application/pdf" xmlns:xmlmime="http://www.w3.org/2004/06/xmlmime">
                    <xop:Include xmlns:xop="http://www.w3.org/2004/08/xop/include" href="cid:report1"></xop:Include>
                </payload:content>
            </payload:report>
        </payload:reports>
    </payload:receiveReport>
XML;
$report1 = file_get_contents("samplePDF.pdf");

$responseMessage = new WSMessage($responsePayloadString, 
        array("attachments" => array("report1" => $report1),
                "useWSA" => TRUE));  
return $responseMessage;    
}

$operations = array("receiveReport" => "sendAttachment");

$service = new WSService(array("operations" => $operations, 
                                            "requestXOP" => TRUE, 
                                            "useMTOM" => TRUE));

$service->reply();

?>
```

**Client Code:**

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL); 
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

/******* FirePHP Debug *******/
require_once('../FirePHPCore/FirePHP.class.php');
ob_start();
$firephp = FirePHP::getInstance(true);
/******* FirePHP Debug *******/

$requestPayloadString = <<<XML
<receiveReport></receiveReport>
```

XML;

```
try {
$client = new WSClient(
    array( "to" => "http://localhost/ReportDL/ReportService.php",
           "useMTOM" => TRUE,
           "responseXOP" => TRUE,
           "useWSA" => TRUE));

$requestMessage = new WSMessage($requestPayloadString);                    
$responseMessage = $client->request($requestMessage);

$cid2stringMap = $responseMessage->attachments;
$cid2contentMap = $responseMessage->cid2contentType;

if($cid2stringMap && $cid2contentMap){
    foreach($cid2stringMap as $i=>$value){
        $f = $cid2stringMap[$i];
        $contentType = $cid2contentMap[$i];

        $firephp->log($f, "pdf");       //DEBUG

    }
}else{
    printf("attachments not received ");
}

} catch (Exception $e) {

if ($e instanceof WSFault) {
    printf("Soap Fault: %s\n", $e->Reason);
} else {
    printf("Message = %s\n",$e->getMessage());
}
}

?>
```

**Edit2:**

```
string '%PDF-1.5
%âãÏÓ
2 0 obj
<</Length 285/Filter/FlateDecode>>stream
xœ’_KÃ0Åßó)î£‚Ä{“4i|S¨‚ÓÀžµKiçÚ­0¿½i;ëýƒ#ÐÐÃýœž¦dwŽI
&ÒàV,qlÁJfŒ�%hCåÙ’­;YÇªÕrÿÎÿêeã|}O@\Æ0,‹<ÌXÃ¤E¯6OW°‹‡z
ñÑ
Z¸}¼t]®æ$ä’Õð³ToGÞ!5¾í»R ›4Ù<)¤:•&ž@©ù¸v’4Â®ƒžB®gÁ6è49X»P‚c@uÌíPñîÝÃÒ¿Â“ß|V;Hö/Å&÷Ðw?f    I.MHq²Mö>­w~5k$‘8Šq£ç:õÛmVçù?òi©ý'Ó-Í^$eNðÿ\¥sá6ø(¼`ßè¿Á÷
endstream
endobj
6 0 obj
<</Type/Catalog/PageMode/UseNone/Pages 3 0 R>>
endobj
7 0 obj
<</Creator(BIRT Report Engine 2.6.0 using iText version unknown.)/Producer('... (length=1231)
```

Comment: Does `file.pdf` exist? Does the web server reading it via `file_get_contents()` have read permissions on it?

Comment: Say output of `file_exists("file.pdf")` and let us know!

Comment: That single piece of code seems to be out of context. Could you show how you use it?

Comment: It is not documented anywhere (surprise surprise) that `file_get_contents()` will ever return `NULL`, it should return `FALSE` on failure. I wonder if the file is too large to be read into memory? Make sure you have `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` and see if you get any meaningful errors.

Comment: As written here: http://php.net/file_get_contents - this function returns `string` or `FALSE` on failure. No mention of returning `NULL`. You sure that the `file.pdf` file is valid PDF file and doesn't contain a string `NULL`???

Comment: @DaveRandom where do I have to put error_reporting and ini_set?

Comment: @petter386 Anywhere before the `file_get_contents()` call - "standard practice" would be to put them as the first two lines in the script, but as long as they are called before `file_get_contents()` they will have the desired effect. How large is the PDF file, out of interest?

Comment: @Repox I'm using WSO2 WSF/PHP and I would like to send PDF as a MTOM attachment with a service response. It's working well if I send image, but it doesn't for PDF.

Comment: @DaveRandom Thanks, I will try that now. 
PDF's size is 1,20 KB

Comment: @petter386 Still doesn't show context - you are most likely doing something wrong. How do you conclude that `file_get_contents('file.pdf');` is null? Is it a `var_dump();` on the function? Or maybe on the variable? How do you make sure that the file you're trying to read exists? What do you do with your function? We need context in code.

Comment: @DaveRandom I added those two lines of code at the beginning but it doesn't show any errors.

Comment: @Repox I'm using FirePHP debugging and it says it's null. If still needed I can post service and client code. As suggested I used file_exists() and it returned 1.

Comment: @petter386 I think we have reached a point where we can't help you without seeing more code.

Comment: @petter386 Well, we need to see your code surrounding the issue. It's as simple as that.

Comment: @petter386 What does `var_dump($report1);` give you if you place it after `$report1 = file_get_contents("samplePDF.pdf");`

Comment: @DaveRandom @Repox The only problem is that `file_get_contents()` doesn't return anything for a pdf file. I wrote another php script with only that one line of code(beside FirePHP debugging stuff) and if I pass .jpg image as a parameter it returns some unreadable encoded string(that's ok because it's an image), but if I pass any .pdf file it says NULL.

Comment: @petter386 I guess that means you didn't try to `var_dump($report1);`? Stop talking about FirePHP; give us some real debugging info!

Comment: @Repox It seems that I can't debugg service code so I did var_dump in a file mentionend in my previous comment and it printed a few lines. I will add it to my question right away.

Comment: @Repox, here you go. I have no idea what that output says. Do you know what that means? Do you see any solution how to read pdf?

Comment: @petter386 The PDF is indeed read by `file_get_contents()` and does not return `NULL` as you are suggesting (otherwise you wouldn't get the data from your second edit). The problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: @Repox you are right. But what can I do now?

Comment: @petter386 Continue debugging in a procedural way to you find out where the data dissappears.

Comment: @Repox thanks a lot for your help!!! Write an answer with your conclusions and I will accept it. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`file_get_contents()` should return `FALSE`if a file is unreadable - otherwise it return a string containing the files content.

The problem must lie elsewhere - start debugging your code in a procedural way with `var_dump()` to find out where your data is lost.

Comment: not agree, php return error 500 in many servers, not a boolean

Comment: Hi @FernandoTorres Thank you for stirring up a question that is almost 8 years old. I'm unsure as to what your comment is trying to achieve, but you can't argue with the documentation. `file_get_contents()` [does indeed return false](https://www.php.net/file_get_contents) if reading a file fails. PHP does not "return error 500 in many servers" when `file_get_contents()`  cannot read a file.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the following code at the top of your PHP page.

```
header("Content-type:application/pdf");
```

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else comes here for this, my issue was the file Permissions weren't correct for www-data.  Once permissions were changed, the web server could read it and functioned as expected.

I know it's a "duh" thing, but it wasn't obvious to me at first.

```
if ($file_ext == 'pdf') { $content_type = "application/pdf"; }
    elseif($file_ext == 'ppt') { $content_type = "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint"; }
    elseif($file_ext == 'pptx') { $content_type = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation"; }
    elseif($file_ext == 'xls') { $content_type = "application/vnd.ms-excel"; }
    elseif($file_ext == 'xlsx') { $content_type = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"; }
    elseif($file_ext == 'doc') { $content_type = "application/vnd.ms-word"; }
    elseif($file_ext == 'docx') { $content_type = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document"; }
        else { $content_type = "application/octet-stream"; }

$document_contents = file_get_contents("/Server/location/to/$file");

header("Content-type: $content_type");
echo $document_contents;
die();
```